# Zend/Controller/Action.php file missing

Tags: zend-framework

I'm new to Zend framework, and was trying out the Guestbook tutorial that Zend has on it's web site. I have the latest framework downloaded and setup properly; php.ini include_files has the  library location set correctly. In the Guestbook tutorial, the GuestbookController extends Zend_Controller_Action and that's what I typed, but I keep getting error stating that Zend_Controller_Action is not found. Turns out, the folder Controller is missing from /library/Zend. I tried re-downloading Zend Framework thinking I might have accidentally deleted it, but it's not in the newly downloaded framework directory either. So, where can I get the Controller folder that contains all the required class files? Or how can I fix the issue? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Kuni

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the tutorial you are following is for ZF1. ZF2 was released last year and works quite differently. You might want to try the quickstart from the current manual instead:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html

Alternatively you can still download version 1.12 from the Zend site.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. That makes sense. I was successfully able to work out this tutorial. I have a different concern now. I wanna try building my own database and model. I have the small database for practice, but contains more than two tables. The tutorial only has one table. Do you know of any example/tutorial where they worked on models with multiple tables?